Not able to get instagram conversations through facebook graph api
I am using this api with page access token
https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/PAGE_ID/conversations?limit=10&platform=INSTAGRAM

I am getting empty response:
Response: { "data": [ ] }

Is there any way to resolve this? I have tried to fetch the instagram conversations of the user but I am getting empty data array
